# Finding and displaying all user using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display all user who have same **id** with the **user id**

Suppose **pim za** is user and her id = 1 , I want to display who all have **oid**= 1.

I am facing problem in displaying them. I want it to display all user and end when there is no user left.

I am using following way:

```
$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblfduser WHERE id='$user->id'");
```

The display should be as follow:

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: And why this query doesn't work ?

Comment: i know this will work. but i need addition codes

Comment: Could you tell us what are these *addition codes*?

Comment: this query will just find user. but i am having problem in displaying them.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You should tell us what have you tried to display these users and show us some code.

Comment: i dont know why my question is so down vote lol but thanks so much it is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$CheckQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE id='".$user->id."'");
```

now after query you can get associative array as below.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($CheckQuery))
{
    echo $row['uname']."<br/>";
}
```

Please do not use `mysql_*` as its deprecated.

be careful with sql injection

Comment: Since `$user->id` is inside double quote `"` the variable is interpreted by PHP. I don't see how your snippet differ than the one from the question ...

Comment: @j0k that is just typo i missly wrote that...sorry if its force you to down vote me...so sorry..

Comment: @deerox always welcome bro..

Comment: i did :D you need to wait for 15 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Fname, a.Lname, a.OID,
        b.ID bID, 
        b.Fname oFNAME, 
        b.Lname oLNAME 
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.id = b.oid
ORDER BY a.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4815/5)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with filter*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4815/6)

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:
(I would believe this is right way using PDO)

Your YourClass;
Your Function:

```
public static function getByOid( $oid ) {
$conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE oid = :oid";
$st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$st->bindValue( ":oid", $oid, PDO::PARAM_INT );
$st->execute();
$row = $st->fetch();
$conn = null;
if ( $row ) return new YourClass( $row );
}
```

and Calling class::function:

```
$results['oid'] = YourClass::getByOid( (int)$_GET["oid"] );
```

and on your page, fetching results:

```
using "foreach"
```